# How to do matrix or vector multiplications based on names of matrix in R

Tags: r, vector, matrix, match

I have object a (first rows are names):

```
26/03/2012  02/04/2012  09/04/2012  16/04/2012  23/04/2012  30/04/2012  07/05/2012  14/05/2012
10          20          50          20          10           0          3          15
```

object b (first rows are names):

```
16/04/2012  23/04/2012  30/04/2012  07/05/2012
6           20          8           2
```

I would like to do a simple multiplication, but based on where the names match
i.e. I would like the output to be

```
16/04/2012  23/04/2012  30/04/2012  07/05/2012
120         200         0           6
```

What is the best way to do this? Some kind of condition on names matching would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to find the names that show up in both vectors and use those common names to select the elements in each vector:

```
v1 <-c(10, 20, 50, 20, 10, 0, 3, 15)
names(v1) <- c("26/03/2012", "02/04/2012", "09/04/2012", "16/04/2012", "23/04/2012", 
"30/04/2012", "07/05/2012", "14/05/2012")
v2 <- c(6, 20, 8, 2)
names(v2) <- c("16/04/2012", "23/04/2012", "30/04/2012", "07/05/2012")
id <- intersect(names(v1), names(v2))
v1[id] * v2[id]
# 16/04/2012 23/04/2012 30/04/2012 07/05/2012 
#        120        200          0          6
```